# Push new value to existing map in angular and map binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Angularjs code.

```
$scope.model;
```

I defined my new object in angular like following

```
$scope.newRelation = {
    relationType : null,
    relatedModel : null
};
```

HTML

```
         <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td><select class="form-control"
                            ng-model="newRelation.relationType" required
                            ng-options="modeltype as modeltype for modeltype in modeltypes"></select>
                        </td>
                        <td><select class="form-control"
                            ng-model="newRelation.relatedModel" required
                            ng-options="model.name as model.name for model in models"></select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                ng-click="addRelation()">Add Relation</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Angular code

```
$scope.addRelation = function()
{
  $scope.model.relations.push($scope.newRelation);
};
```

When i click form save the model.relations values are empty in the back end.Any clues ? Please let me know if i need to provide more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You directly assigned object to list.

It'll keep reference.

make a copy

```
var obj=angular.copy($scope.newRelation);
```

Then push it

```
 $scope.model.relations.push(obj);
```